# Business and data layer in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new  to ASP.net MVC architecture. I have read in some articles that Model will contain business and data access logic. So does this mean that i have to implement the business and data access layrers in side model folder?
And it is obviously not possible to add class libraries (business layer and Data access layer of n tier) in Model folder. SO please let me know how to design business and data layer if i dont want to include my LINQ queries in Controller.

Thanks,
Amith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing Business Object/Data Layer, just reference those DLLs, you dont need to use the Models folder. MVC uses DTO/ViewData objects a lot, those can go in the Models folders if you dont put them in your dlls.

Comment: ok..but this is a new application. I have to write new business and datalayer.

Comment: Am I wrong, or couldnt you just make your own "Businesslayer" folder and keep everything in there? or is that a wrong approach?

Comment: If I may ask, what difference is between data layer and data access layer?

Comment: The data layer can be seen as the database itself and the data access layer is the code that interacts with the database.